# Arch is larger than Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I noticed after downloading the Raspbian Wheezy and Arch ARM distros for the Raspberry Pi that Arch is 2GB whilst Raspbian is only 1.9GB.

How is Arch larger than Raspbian, surely Arch is very lightweight, and Raspbain comes with a lot more installed than Arch does like LXDE?

Not really an important question as such, just something that has me slightly confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size you see is the size of the image, the 'raw backup' of the partition that has been created on the SD card. This partition could be empty while the image is still 2GB. So the size you are wondering about has nothing to do with how many files are installed on the partition itself. The reason of the difference might be that Raspbian uses a slightly smaller partition to create the OS on, with the reason to be very sure it will fit on every 2GB SD card that is sold.

A 2GB SD card is not always 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 bytes, it might vary a little from brand to brand. Using a 1.9GB image ensures that it should fit on any 2GB SD card.

But this is just a guess of WHY it is a little smaller.